# YouTube API stops listening for events after video change

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

Say I need to change videos by clicking the button and getting new link from array. 
However, every time `src` gets different video link `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` stops listening 
for `onStateChange` event and my video is not looped anymore. The question is not about looping, 
but in general how can I keep event listener when changing player's `src`?

```js
var videoz = [
        {youTube: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/HcGG0tXv_U4?showinfo=0&controls=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&start=20&end=23&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1'},
        {youTube: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/UVwJimrX3tg?showinfo=0&controls=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&start=23&end=25&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1'}],
    player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { 
    document.getElementById('vidVid').src = videoz[0].youTube;
    player = new YT.Player('vidVid', {events:{onStateChange: playerVidEnd}}); 
}

function changeVid() {
    document.getElementById('vidVid').src = videoz[1].youTube;
}

function playerVidEnd(event) {
    if (event.data == 0) {
           player.seekTo(20);
           player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="vidVid" style="width: 500px; height: 400px" src=""></iframe>
    <button onclick="changeVid()" type="button" id="nxt">NEXT</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out

## option 1

Try when you change the video src to reinitialize the player.

## option 2 (recommended by the docs)

Place this in your change function

```
player.loadVideoByUrl({
    videoz[1].youTube,
    23 /* start */,
    25 /* end */,
    "highres"
})
```